# Can the number of moles be a ratio of mass percentage and molecular mass?

Tags: physical-chemistry, mole

I recently started studying mole concept and came across this formula,
$$ n=\frac{\text{mass percentage}}{\text{molecular mass}}$$

I don't know how it came into existence. How does this formula work?

Comment: Never saw this before. What is the context?

Comment: Aside of easy dimension check, do not confuse molar and molecular mass. // We do not say number of kilograms either.

Answer (score 2):

The exact formula is :  $n = \ce{\frac{mass}{molar mass}}$. It is not : $n = \ce{\frac{mass percentage}{molar mass}}$, as written in your text. "My" formula can be checked by dimension analysis. The mass is expressed in grams. The molar mass is expressed in gram per mole. The unit of ratio $n$ by "my" formula is expressed in $\ce{\frac{gram}{g/mol} = mol}$. And, of course, the mole is the unit of amount of matter (what you call "number of moles")

Comment: Actually, the base SI unit for the mass is kilogramme. But that is (all in all) irrelevant to this answer.